# Is quorum needed in Keycloak Standalone Clustered Configuration?

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, wildfly-10, infinispan, redhat-sso

It's stated that Keycloak is built on top of the WildFly application server and its sub-projects like Infinispan (for caching) and Hibernate (for persistence).

Keycloak recommends to look in [WildFly Documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/16/Admin_Guide.html) and [High Availability Guide](https://docs.wildfly.org/16/High_Availability_Guide.html).

If understood correctly Standalone Clustered Configuration allows session replication or transmission of SSO contexts around the cluster.

I don't understand though if odd number of Keycloak nodes is required so that there will be quorum.

[Singleton subsystem](https://docs.wildfly.org/16/High_Availability_Guide.html#HA_Singleton_Features) states

> 10.1.3. Quorum Network partitions are particularly problematic for singleton services, since they can trigger multiple singleton
>   providers for the same service to run at the same time. To defend
>   against this scenario, a singleton policy may define a quorum that
>   requires a minimum number of nodes to be present before a singleton
>   provider election can take place. A typical deployment scenario uses a
>   quorum of N/2 + 1, where N is the anticipated cluster size. This value
>   can be updated at runtime, and will immediately affect any active
>   singleton services. e.g.

Is it somehow related to Keycloak and its Standalone Clustered Configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Response](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2019-August/018909.html) from Keycloak mailing list:

No, Keycloak uses Infinispan for caching and Infinispan uses JGroups for
clustering. JGroups doesn't need consensus.

> It's stated that Keycloak is built on top of the WildFly application
>   server and its sub-projects like Infinispan (for caching) and Hibernate
>   (for persistence).
>
> Keycloak recommends to look in WildFly Documentation and High Availability
>   Guide.
>
> If understood correctly Standalone Clustered Configuration allows session
>   replication or transmission of SSO contexts around the cluster.
>
> I don't understand though if odd number of Keycloak nodes is required so
>   that there will be quorum.

No it is not strictly required. As in almost all distributed systems,
having odd number of nodes helps recovering from Split Brain scenarios.